# Is there a way to make Odoo run on https using gcp classic load balancer?

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-load-balancer, gcp-load-balancer, odoo-16

I have installed the Odoo on gcp vm instances and configure the classic load balancer for the same, just like my other servers. But Odoo is running on http only, I have to put https manually then only it works but when I login it goes back to http and I have to put https again manually. Is there a way to configure so that it works on https.

Even I have redirected Odoo to work on port 80 instead of port 8069. Even after that it is not working automatically on https.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Odoo version 16 , please check if **Direct Devices** is enabled in point of sale settings. If it is enabled, the default protocol will be **HTTP**.

In order to have the point of sale to use a secure connection (**HTTPs**),  a new Key needs to be added in the system parameters settings as mentioned below.

- Please activate the developer mode.
- Goto Settings ‣ Technical ‣ Parameters ‣ System Parameters
- Create a new parameter and add the following values.

> ```
> Key: point_of_sale.enforce_https
> Value: True
> ```

- Click on Save.

This will enable the **HTTPs** protocol accordingly.

The above information is provided in the official [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/applications/sales/point_of_sale/overview/https.html).

Comment: Hi, I have followed the given steps. Still it is not working on https, But I have found one thing there is a key called "web.base.url having value "http://mydomain". Every time I changing this to "https://mydomain" and saving also but once I logout it gets back to "http://mydomain". Is this having connection with this https issue and yes, Is there any way to resolve this? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your update. Can you please check in system parameters if the web.base.url is updated with HTTPs and web.base.url.freeze is set as TRUE.

Comment: web.base.url.freeze is TRUE but web.base.url is set to http. I am changing this to https but everytime I logout it changes automatically to http

Comment: Please check the official documentation https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/administration/install/deploy.html#https 
regarding HTTPs connection. This can be useful to you.

Comment: @Vishakha is your issue resolved? let me know if you need any additional help

Comment: Hi, still not resolved...actually we have paused oodo for a while.